# Find HTML elements have same data attribute values as button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering is there any way to find the HTML element on page (form, div etc) which has same `data attribute value` as the click button and next load that matched element into DOM.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      var btn = $(this).attr("data-value");
      alert(btn);
      //From Where I have to go to fetch the right matching element???
      var element = $(".Form").html();
      alert(element);

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="Form" data-value="1">
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <h4>I'm First Element</h4>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="Form" data-value="2">
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <h4>I'm Second Element</h4>
  </form>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn" data-value="1">Find One</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" data-value="2">Find Two</button>
```

Comment: **1.** No need of `each` here, `click` will bind the event on all the matched elements. **2.** You can use `data('value')` to get the `data-value` attribute value **3.** **Answer:** To get all the elements with same data value, use `$('[data-value="' + value '"]')`

Comment: Missed `+` in the third point above, `$('[data-value="' + value + '"]')`

Comment: yup, worked, thanks, saved me couple of hours.

Comment: Welcome! Glad to help :)

Comment: @Tushar, did you ask something? I missed the comment, I was banging my head to make the code work in B.S with remote content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select element by jquery selector.

```
$(this).click(function () {
                var btn = $(this).attr("data-value");
                alert(btn);
                //From Where I have to go to fetch the right matching element???
                var element = $('.Form[data-value="' + btn + '"]');
                alert(element);
            });
```

`element` is a jquery object. Now you can use this element to do your requirements.

Comment: Reason accepting your answer, you added `selector` which match the `data-value`, without selector, jQuery may only return the closest element as object which in my case was returning the `btn` as `Find One` but after adding `selector`, works like charm.

Answer (score 2):

Update your JavaScript Function like follow

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".btn").click(function() {
      var btn = $(this).attr("data-value");
      alert(btn);
      //From Where I have to go to fetch the right matching element???
      var element = $('[data-value="' + btn +'"]').html();
      alert(element);

    }); 
});
```